# Populate ComboBox based on another ComboBox using XAML

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, data-binding, linq-to-entities

I have two ComboBoxes

```
<ComboBox Name="cmbMake" DisplayMemberPath="MakeName" SelectedValuePath="MakeID"/>
<ComboBox Name="cmbModel" DisplayMemberPath="ModelName"/>
```

I use LINQ-to-Entities to populate the **cmbGroup** ComboBox

```
Dim db as myDataEntity
cmbGroup.ItemsSource = db.Makes
```

How do I populate my second ComboBox (**cmbModels**) based on the selection of the first ComboBox (**cmbMake**) using XAML so that whatever I select in the first ComboBox automatically filters the ItemsSource in the second ComboBox?

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am posting the full solution here

## XAML

```
<ComboBox Name="cmbMake" DisplayMemberPath="MakeName" SelectedValuePath="MakeID"  Width="200"/>
<ComboBox Name="cmbModel" DisplayMemberPath="ModelName" DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=cmbMake}" Width="200"/>
```

## CODE-BEHIND

```
Private Sub cmbMake_SelectionChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles cmbMake.SelectionChanged

        Dim myItem = From m In myModel
                     Where m.MakeID = cmbMake.SelectedValue

        cmbModel.ItemsSource = myItem

End Sub
```

Whenever the value is changed in the cmbModel ComboBox it will use LINQ to reset the **ItemsSource** of the cmbModel ComboBox.

### Many Thanks to @XAMeLi for the helping hand!

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a Prism MVVM solution.

Answer (score 4):

If your data is hierarchical, where each item in db.Makes holds a list of the Models (and lets say this list is in a property called MyModelsList), then:

```
<ComboBox Name="cmbMake" DisplayMemberPath="MakeName" SelectedValuePath="MakeID"/>
<ComboBox Name="cmbModel" DisplayMemberPath="ModelName" DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=cmbMake}" ItemsSource="{Binding MyModelsList}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks @XAMeLi I was able to use your suggestion to get it to work!

Answer (score 3):

It should be possible to use a converter to filter the items, for that you can employ a [`MultiBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx) to get the values for the items and the selection in the other box in.

Would look something like this:

```
<ComboBox Name="cmbModel" DisplayMemberPath="ModelName">
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <MutliBinding>
           <MultiBinding.Converter>
               <vc:MyFilterConverter/>
           </MultiBinding.Converter>
           <Binding Path="Items"/> <!-- This should bind to your complete items-list -->
           <Binding Path="SelectedValue" ElementName="cmbMake"/>
        </MutliBinding>
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
</ComboBox>
```

The converter needs to implement [`IMultiValueConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx).